# Building Poco C++ libraries on Windows from commandline

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, poco-libraries

I've developed a python script for building a bunch of dependencies that I need for my project. Among them is Poco.

On OS X and Linux I'm using cmake to build Poco and my first thought was to do the same for Windows. It seems, however, that the cmake pipeline isn't supported on Windows (or I'm doing something wrong) which leads me to my question; **how do I go about building Poco for windows from the commandline?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows you will find preconfigured scrips for building POCO using specific VS compiler version i.e. `build_vs120.cmd` or generic one `buildwin.cmd` which you can configure according to what you need:

```
C:\dev\workspace\poco-1.6.0>buildwin.cmd
Usage:
------
buildwin VS_VERSION [ACTION] [LINKMODE] [CONFIGURATION] [PLATFORM] [SAMPLES] [TESTS] [TOOL]
VS_VERSION:    "90|100|110|120"
ACTION:        "build|rebuild|clean"
LINKMODE:      "static_mt|static_md|shared|all"
CONFIGURATION: "release|debug|both"
PLATFORM:      "Win32|x64|WinCE|WEC2013"
SAMPLES:       "samples|nosamples"
TESTS:         "tests|notests"
TOOL:          "devenv|vcexpress|wdexpress|msbuild"

Default is build all.
```

NOTE: You may need to download sources for Windows

**Edit:** There doesn't seem to be an install equivalent on Windows for when using the build batch script. In order to mimic linux install, one needs to merge all `include` folders into one, so basically copy `include` folders from `Foundation`, `JSON`, `Net`, `Util`, `XML`, and so on into one location by overwriting them. All folders except Foundation which is a Poco core namespace have structure: `{Name}/include/Poco/{Name}`, i.e. `Util/include/Poco/Util` so they will merge without any problem. As a result one should get the following structure: `include/Poco/*` This should be easy to scriptize too.

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out once I get a chance.

Comment: I currently have a partial solution using the above script, which works fine for building the *.lib and *.dll files. I don't seem to get the resulting include folder I do when running cpack on *nix systems. What would be the proper way to get that?

Comment: @JBarberU I've edited my answer where I explained how you can prepare the resulting include folder

Comment: Got the job done using the above mentioned script and manually copying the include files from my wrapping python script. I used the components file to select the proper subdirectories to pick the includes from.